# Spring Kafka - How to start the container which is running in a POD

Tags: openshift, spring-kafka

My requirements are:

If target service is down then stop the kafka listener which can be achieved by using
ContainerStoppingErrorHandler.

Now once container is stopped then

> "how can we start the container in Spring Kafka"

Considering that POD is running with consumer, producer and rest services application. there will be multiple instance of POD (openshift) running with these applications.

Comment: Openshift has a REST API... Not sure how this is a spring-kafka question

Comment: could you elaborate your answer?

Comment: "How to start container in Spring Kafka" - You don't. You start it in your application. And you use an HTTP client to create a Deployment/Pod https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/rest_api/workloads_apis/deployment-apps-v1.html#deployment-apps-v1. Otherwise, the question doesn't make sense; kubernetes pods and Docker containers are equivalent names, if the container is stopped, so is the pod, as well as any code running in it